# How to show that a point is in closure of set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A$ be an open set in $R^n$ and $a$ is an interior point of $A$. Set $\delta=\inf\{\|x-a\|:x\in bd(A)\}$, where $bd(A)$ is the set of all boundary point of $A$. 
For given point $u\in R^n$ with $\|u\|=1$, is it possible to show that $a+\delta u \in cl(A)$, where $cl(A)$ is the set of all closure of $A$.

Comment: See if you can show that $a+tu\in\operatorname{int}(A)$ for all $0\leq t<\delta$, where $\operatorname{int}(A)$ denotes the interior of $A$.